# Switching between Auto Layout ON / OFF, in different ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I have a scrolling view, where I need Auto Layout turned ON to accomplish what I want. But Auto Layout is giving troubles in my second ViewController, and therefor turned OFF.

Is there any problem switching between Auto Layout ON / OFF, in different ViewControllers?

Hope to find answer here, and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Should be no problem at all.  I've done just that several times before. :)

Comment: I have done it too. I did not get any issue.